# Piecewise Recursive function with 2 arguments

Tags: functions, piecewise

The following code is not working for argument nn>1. Hold statement `Hold[0.62+v0[1,0]]` come as output for `v0[2,0]`.

```
v0[0, 0] = 0.12; v0[nn_, ll_] = PiecewiseExpand[ Piecewise[{{v0[nn - 1, 0] + 0.02 ll (3 ll + 5) + 1/2,nn != 0 && ll != 0}, {v0[nn - 1, 0] + 1/2,nn != 0 && ll == 0}, {v0[0, 0] + 0.02 ll (3 ll + 5),nn == 0 && ll != 0}, {0.12, nn == 0 && ll == 0}}]]
```

I have to use this function as `V0[nn,ll]` further for example:

```
vl[x_] := -((4*as)/(3 x)) + (a*x^2) - v0[nn, ll]
```

I don't know if this requires some loop. Please help. This is my first question here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following

```
v0[0, 0] = 0.12;
v0[nn_, ll_] := 
 PiecewiseExpand[
  Piecewise[{{v0[nn - 1, 0] + 0.02 ll (3 ll + 5) + 1/2, 
     nn != 0 && ll != 0}, {v0[nn - 1, 0] + 1/2, 
     nn != 0 && ll == 0}, {v0[0, 0] + 0.02 ll (3 ll + 5), 
     nn == 0 && ll != 0}, {0.12, nn == 0 && ll == 0}}]]
```

works fine as you can see

```
Column@Table[v0[ii, ll], {ii, 1, 5}] // TableForm
```

> [image: col]

And also,

```
vl[x_, nn_ : 0, ll_ : 0] := -((4*as)/(3 x)) + (a*x^2) - v0[nn, ll]
```

runs without issues. Test it

```
vl[x]
```

returns

> [image: res2]

Also, you can do

```
Column@Table[vl[x], {x, 2, 10}]
```

> [image: c2]

And of course, you can change `nn` and `ll` to whatever you want

```
Column@Table[vl[2, xx, ll], {xx, 2, 10}]
```

> [image: cf]

Comment: The problem is after running the definition of `v0[nn,ll]` again, this gives me `$RecursionLimit` problem. But, I guess I do not need to run it again. Thanks.

Comment: @kdteam1 please copy the code as i wrote it and try with a clean kernel. do a `Quit[]` and then run the code